# BufferingResponseListener and getContentAsString append the previously fetched content

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I run a custom WebSocketServlet for Jetty, which sends short text push notifications (for an async mobile and [desktop word game](https://www.facebook.com/games/slova-farbera/)) to many platforms (Facebook, Vk.com, Mail.ru, Ok.ru also Firebase and Amazon messaging) using a Jetty HttpClient instance:

```
public class MyServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    private final SslContextFactory mSslFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    private final HttpClient mHttpClient = new HttpClient(mSslFactory);

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        try {
            mHttpClient.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }

        mFcm      = new Fcm(mHttpClient);    // Firebase
        mAdm      = new Adm(mHttpClient);    // Amazon
        mApns     = new Apns(mHttpClient);   // Apple
        mFacebook = new Facebook(mHttpClient);
        mMailru   = new Mailru(mHttpClient);
        mOk       = new Ok(mHttpClient);
        mVk       = new Vk(mHttpClient);
    }
```

This has worked very good for the past year, but since I have recently upgraded my WAR-file to use Jetty 9.4.14.v20181114 the trouble has begun -

```
public class Facebook {
    private final static String APP_ID      = "XXXXX";
    private final static String APP_SECRET  = "XXXXX";
    private final static String MESSAGE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s/notifications?" +
            // the app access token is: "app id | app secret"
            "access_token=%s%%7C%s" +
            "&template=%s";

    private final HttpClient mHttpClient;

    public Facebook(HttpClient httpClient) {
        mHttpClient = httpClient;
    }

    private final BufferingResponseListener mMessageListener = new BufferingResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result) {
            if (!result.isSucceeded()) {
                LOG.warn("facebook failure: {}", result.getFailure());
                return;
            }

            try {
                // THE jsonStr SUDDENLY CONTAINS PREVIOUS CONTENT!
                String jsonStr = getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                LOG.info("facebook success: {}", jsonStr);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.warn("facebook exception: ", ex);
            }
        }
    };

    public void postMessage(int uid, String sid, String body) {
        String url = String.format(MESSAGE_URL, sid, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, UrlEncoded.encodeString(body));
        mHttpClient.POST(url).send(mMessageListener);
    }
}
```

Suddenly the `getContentAsString` method called for successful HttpClient invocations started to deliver the strings, which were fetched previously - *prepended* to the the actual result string.

What could it be please, is it some changed [BufferingResponseListener](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.14.v20181114/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/BufferingResponseListener.html) behaviour or maybe some non-obvious Java quirk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferingResponseListener` was never intended to be reusable across requests.

Just allocate a new `BufferingResponseListener` for every request/response.